# uniq char that need to replaced without to put the "\"

Tags: perl

I need to know if there is some way to replace any string as @ or * or ? or & without to put the "\" before it

Example

```
perl -pe 'next if /^#/; s/\@d\&/new_value/ if /param5/'  test
```

in this example need to replace the @d& with new_value
but I need to put the "\" before @ or &
can be other way without to put the "\" because I have random char that can be in the old value.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 'next if /^#/; my $regex=q/@d&/; s/$regex/new_value/ if /param5/'  test
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem for regex metacharacters like .*?+[]{}.  What you are looking for is `quotemeta`.